# Can we block some cities or towns in Magento?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I want to ship only certain towns and cities my products in magento. I'd prefer dropdown cities and towns instead of inputboxes in frontend... Is there any extensions, codes or settings in magento for that?

Comment: can you be more specific because i can not understand well what you want. You can choose to what countries you want your products to be shipped and that's can be done through System -> Configuration -> General -> Countries options.

Comment: If you read the question well i especially highlighted "Towns and Cities" words 2 times... Fresh products cant be shipped far countries so i dont want customers who are from distant countries to make orders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter values in this two following tables, ***directory_country_region*** & ***directory_country_region_name***

This is a link which might help you to understand the whole process http://puzzlersworld.com/technical/how-to-add-new-regionstate-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out [Zones Manager](http://innoexts.com/zone-release-1000/) extension? It can help you to block cities or towns by setting up zones by geography (countries / states / regions/ zip codes/ zip code ranges) and restricting them by product categories / subcategories or by shipping methods and some more.